# Parsing data into a struct array

Tags: matlab, parsing

I have a file which I read via the textscan function, this is stored into a 1x6 cell array of the form

```
[354018x1 uint64]    {354018x1 cell}    [354018x1 uint64]    [354018x1 uint64]    {354018x1 cell}    {354018x1 cell}
```

Now I would like to have a struct array with approprotate filed names, I followed http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/programatically-creating-a-struct/ and came up with

```
>> snames = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
>> arglist = {snames{:}; obj.components{:}};
>> s = struct(arglist{:});
```

Unfortunately, in every row the complete array [354018x1 uint64] is stored, e.g.

```
s(1)

ans = 

a: [354018x1 uint64]
b: 'test'
c: [354018x1 uint64]
d: [354018x1 uint64]
e: 'test4'
f: 'ob'
```

How do I get each element in each respective row without using a loop?

This is what I get if I use cell2struct

```
>> f = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}; s = cell2struct(C,f,2);
>> s(1)

ans = 

a: [354018x1 uint64]
b: {354018x1 cell}
c: [354018x1 uint64]
d: [354018x1 uint64]
e: {354018x1 cell}
f: {354018x1 cell}
```

Comment: Have you tried cell2struct?

Comment: What loop? Try this - f = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
s = cell2struct(C1,f,2);, where C1 is the 1x6 input cell array.

Comment: @Divakar added what happens if I use you variant. I want to access every row, i.e s(1), ... s(354018)

Answer (score 0):

This uses loops, but only per row, and not per column, which is what I presume you're trying to avoid.  It makes use of dynamic field references to create the structure, (http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/), and I assume you know what lines contain what type of value, otherwise it becomes a bit more complicated.

Essentially, you build one cell array of strings, and then loop the rows, assigning them to the proper structure/structure field with a datatype conversion as necessary.  You could probably do it without the loops using `cellfun`, but it'd be messy (I think) to work the datatype conversion test in there.  At any rate, you are not looping over the 300k+ columns but only the 6 rows, so the performance shouldn't improve much.

```
% matlab_test_2.txt:
% 1 3 5 7 9 10
% test
% 1 9 10 23
% 23 11 94 4
% testy
% testless

clear all;
fclose('all');
file = '<path>/matlab_test_2.txt';
f = fopen(file);
c = textscan(f, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
rows_with_numbers = [1 3 4];
rows_with_strings = [2 5 6];
snames = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
for i = 1:length(rows_with_numbers)
    index = rows_with_numbers(i);
    s.(snames{index}) = str2num(c{1}{index});
end
for i = 1:length(rows_with_strings)
    index = rows_with_strings(i);
    s.(snames{index}) = c{1}{index};
end
s

>> cell_test
s = 
    a: [1 3 5 7 9 10]
    c: [1 9 10 23]
    d: [23 11 94 4]
    b: 'test'
    e: 'testy'
    f: 'testless'
```